# AnyTime date picker close with date selection

Tags: javascript, date, picker, anytime

The Any Time date picker doesn't close when the user clicks a date with the mouse, only when they hit enter. How can I make it so it closes with a mouse click? I found this code in anytime.js:

```
if ( this.oDiv && this.oDiv.is(':visible') )
                this.dismissODiv(event);
              else if ( this.yDiv && this.yDiv.is(':visible') )
                this.dismissYDiv(event);
              else if ( this.pop )
                this.dismiss(event);
```

This I believe is the code that executes when the user hits enter. I think I just need to paste this code in the mouse click function, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the function (I haven't tested yet, however), and it's between line `1579`~`1592`.

To find the handler, I first searched jQuery(a JS library which AnyTime date picker is using)'s `.click` function, which is frequently used for handling click events.

One I found was in the `btn()` function, which comment says that this function is for making buttons. Since it is written that `.btn() is called by AnyTime.picker() ... The "handler" is bound to click events for the <div> ...`, next thing I did is to find a code in `Anytime.picker()` function which makes buttons of days.

Then I searched for `Anytime.picker = function(` to find the definition of `Anytime.picker()` function, and I found that `askDoM` variable (in line `1452`) is used to determine whether the day of month is 'asked'.

From that, I easily found the code making buttons of days which starts from line `1557`, and then I found the code calling `btn` function with the handler.

Comment: Thank you. I inserted the copied code into `if( dom )` on line 1585. Right after the line `this.upd(elem);` on 1590. Works perfectly.

Comment: If anyone finds this thread and needs assistance with the library, please note that you can contact me directly via the links on my website.